# Selenium / Appium Parallel Execution using JUnit 4

Tags: multithreading, selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver, appium

Trying to execute appium tests parallely on multiple devices. Idea goes like initiating JUnitRunner class as parameterized (e.g. deviceList) that creates parallel thread per device. From runner, invoking TestSuite via JUnitCore.run. Problem is that instantiating driver in test cases need device name (probably from Runner class), but JUnitCore doesnt provide such option (to invoke Suite / Test class by instantiating it). Any help?

Code goes like: JUnitRunner.java

```
@RunWith(Parallelized.class) // extension of the Parameterized runner
    public class JUTRunner {    
    private String device;

    /**
     * @param device
     */
    public JUTRunner(String device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getParameters() {
        List<String> deviceList = findAllDevices();
        List<Object[]> parameters = new ArrayList<Object[]>(deviceList.size());

        for (String device : deviceList) {
            parameters.add(new Object[] { device });
        }
        return parameters;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    private static List<String> findAllDevices() {
        return DeviceList.getInstance().getDeviceList();
    }

    /**
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    @Test
    public void testOnDevice() throws InterruptedException {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(JUTSuite.class);

        Result result = new JUnitCore().run(suite);     
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("All tests finished successfully...");
        }
    }
    }
```

And TestCase.java

```
public class MyTest extends TestCase {
    protected String device;
    protected AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    private int deviceNum;
    @Rule
    public TestName testName = new TestName();

    @Before
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.driver = new AndroidDriver(device).getDriver();
    }
    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
        System.out.println(testName.getMethodName() + device);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I am doing the same with Selenium grid and multi threading, but I also want to do it with JUnitRunner, please update the post if you resolved this problem.